# Multiple script and namespace errors on a previously working Unity project . Type or namespace name 'GUIColorOverride' could not be found

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unity-editor

I had some unusual errors on a relatively small Unity project with six c# scripts written in Visual Studio. It was all working fine, and I came back to it after the weekend. Upon opening, there were 18 new errors which were preventing the code from compiling and I spent several hours trying to figure out what was going on.

The main errors were saying things like `Type or namespace name 'GUIColorOverride' could not be found` and `associated script cannot be loaded, assign a valid script`, even though they were linked and I could see the scripts had no errors in Visual Studio. I even did a full Unity uninstall and rebooted, then a clean install. This didn't fix it.

I tried a number of other things such as backing up the scripts from the assets folder and then deleting them. Opening the project and pasting them back in as 'clean' new scripts. This didn't work. I am using Unity's Cloud Collab so was even able to use this to go back to earlier pushes of the project (which had all worked). Nope.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You should exclude these from the Backup!**

---

Basically you can exclude anything that would also be excluded from git via e.g. [this "official" `.gitignore`](https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/Unity.gitignore) file for Unity projects.

Any file and folder listed here will be regenerated by Unity automatically and should not appear in any version control / Backup.

The entire `Library` folder in particular is part of it since its content changes quite rapidly and is recompiled every time you change a script, install/remove a package etc.

Checkout [Unity Manual - Behind the Scenes](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/BehindtheScenes.html) for more information in detail

> When backing up a project, or adding a project to a Version Control Repository, you should include the main Unity project folder, containing both the `Assets`
>   and `ProjectSettings` folders. All the information in these folders is crucial to the way Unity works. **You should omit the `Library` and `Temp` folders for backup purposes.**

---

To solve an already present issue with the `Library` folder you can most of the times fix it by simply closing Unity, deleting the entire `Library` folder via your file browser and opnening Unity again → Unity will rebuild the `Library`

Answer (score 1):

Solved it! The issue was that the local Projects folder I had been using was connected to Google Backup and Sync. This messed with some of the files in some of the folders in `PackageCache` in Particular in the `MyProject > Library > PackageCache > com.unity.timeline@1.2.13 > Editor >` directory.

[FIX] To fix and prevent this from happening in future, I turned off Google Backup and Sync for my Unity Project(s), and am now exclusively using Unity Collab and Git. Using the specific errors that were showing in the Unity console, I located the exact path of the Unity-created files that were causing these errors in my broken project, and replaced them with the same files from a working project. This fixed all of the errors. There must have been some corrupted or partially synced files in these folders which caused Unity to have a tantrum. Hope that helps someone!